# DOMXPath First Level of Specific Tag

Tags: php, xpath

I'm trying to get the first depth of a tag such as Template in XML.  I'm using the DOMDocument class.  I'd like to get the first depth instance of a Template tag in a structure like:

```
<root>
<div>
    <Template> <--this one
        <Template />
    </Template>
</div>
<Template /> <-- and this one
</root>
```

I've tried the following:

```
$xpath->query('/*/Template[not(ancestor::Template)]')
```

and

```
$xpath->query('/root/Template')
```

The issue with the first example is I don't get any nodes back the second only gets Template nodes after root.  I'd like to get the first level of Template nodes no matter where they exist in the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out the syntax is:

```
$xpath->query('//Template[not(ancestor::Template)]')
```